# pivot_table returns table of wrong length

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I'm having a problem with the output of a the pivot_table function of pandas (python).
I'm trying to pivot a table on the ProductName, setting the CustomerId as the index and aggregating the Quantities, in order to get the total sales per customer and category. The code I use is the following:

```
   products_sum = pd.pivot_table(sales_per_customer, 
        values='Quantity', 
        index='CustomerId', 
        columns='ProductName',
        aggfunc = "sum").reset_index()
   products_sum
```

The problem is that although I have 107157 unique CustomerIds, the pivot_table function returns a dataframe of 106934 rows (missing 223 CustomerIds). I have already checked that there are no null values on the CustomerIds.

Thank you in advance

Comment: pass `dropna=False` as well.

Comment: It would be easier for people to help if you could provide a minimal set of samples in the table; otherwise, it would be hard to tell.

One idea to debug this is to find the missing CustomerIds and look at those data belong to CustomerIds to collect more clues.

Comment: @ThePyGuy Thank you for the answer, I still had no luck..

Comment: @Shao-ChuanWang I have already isolated the missing ones, I will try to see if there is something wrong